# PHP altering HTML on first connection

Tags: javascript, php, html

Currently I have a php-page using `include` to show an html-page.

What I want to do is use a variable the php-page received when being called and project data into a field of the html-page depending on this variable. The problem is that I can't seem to pass the variable from php to html without using html to call php.

I know that I can simply echo the php-part, but because I can't echo straight into one of the html-page's divs it ends up putting the echo at the beginning or end of the page.

What I want to accomplish is for the html-page to load the php-part into one of the div's the first time the php includes the html-page. Is there any way to do such a thing?

If this isn't possible, then how do I get the javascript in the html-page to use the variable from the php-file? Is the best option really the href?

As requested some of the code:
php:

```
if (filter_input(INPUT_GET, "event", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING))
{
  include "../Html/EventPage.html"; //target page
  $temp = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "event", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //get the variable
  include "../PHP/Connector.php"; //include the connection page
  $value = callFunction(Connect(), $temp); //call connection page and return value
  echo "<div class = 'cant select div in html'>" . $value . "</div>"; //echo value in location 
}
```

html:

```
<div id = "dynamic">
   this should have the php
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but your description is confusing. First you state that you do not want to "call" php, later down you claim that this is exactly what you want. It seems you are still a bit confused about the terms. There is not such thing as a "php page". There is no real difference between an html file and a php file, you can simply "mix" both.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried to your question.

Comment: So is your final goal to have php fetched variables in your javascript?

Comment: @arkascha, the point here is that I want a clear difference between frontend and backend. My php is used as backend and my html is obviously frontend. There is a good reason for me not to want these two in the same file and I'm stubborn so I stick to this method. For this reason there is a seperate .php and .html page. I get that in practice the .php page is realy no differend from the .html page, but in this case they are two differend files. I think the confusion is based on that and I get why that wasn't clear. Sorry for that.

Comment: Certainly front and backend are separate things. And certainly you can keep html and php in separate files if you want to, though it will complicate things for no real reason. The only thing visible to the frontend is HTML anyway. My main question was about those terms "html page" and "php page" which do not make any sense at all.

Comment: My final goal is to have the php echo some html into one of the div's of the html page @DavePlug. The php has a few variables that I want to add to the html.

Comment: As I stated before, those were indeed used in a confusing way. My apologies for that @arkascha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you use some code like this to display the page:

```
include('page.html');
```

A safer way would be to prevent evaluation in page.html:

```
echo file_get_contents('page.html', true);
```

You can then do any string modification you want for the content:

```
$replacement = 'MY REPLACEMENT';
echo str_replace('<div id="my-div">', '<div id="my-div">' . $replacement, file_get_contents('page.html', true));
```

Comment: This seems very usefull. I'll try using it and let you know about the results. Thanks for now!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. It perfectly does what I wanted it to do. The safety tip is also appreciated a lot and I have implemented that throughout the code. I tried the code on Firefox, Chrome and IE and it all works. Thanks again for the answer Michael2